# Stop div from moving horizontally on browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a layout having multiple divs, all of same width and height. The width of all divs is 100vw. The problem is that when I resize the browser window, if initially div no 5 was in center, it moves and some other div lands up in the center.

I tried using onresize event and changing scrollLeft for the container element as
container_scrollLeft =  current_div_index * width_of_one_div but this leads to jittery behaviour due to constant manipulation of scrollLeft.

```css
.container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-y: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="height: 400px;">
  <div class="page">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>6</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>8</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>9</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>10</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am preferably looking for a pure CSS solution. However, I welcome javascript based solution too.

Comment: This isn't a solution for your current setup, but you may want to rethink this. By far, the #1 thing users hate is horizontal scrolling. Think about it. Your mousewheel allows for easy vertical scrolling, but not horizontal. Why not just show one div that takes up the full-width of the browser at a time and then provide Previous | Next buttons to replace the shown div with another one, thus only having one div to contend with.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree that horizontal scrolling is not the best thing but actually I am creating a book reader kind of thing where each page is visible in full width at one time. User can scroll snap to next page hence horizontal scrolling is inevitable.

Comment: There is still a better way to do this than to have all the windows laid out and just waiting to be moved into position causing a horizontal scroll, which again is the #1 thing people dislike about web interfaces. There's a difference between swiping right and scrolling right. You can use a CSS animation effect to simulate the window coming in from the right.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry but this is how I need to layout my product. Can you help something in this setup?